# Does $\min |{\cos(n)}|$ exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $f:\mathbb{Z^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(n)=|\cos(n)|$ in radians. Does $\min f$ exist?

I think the answer is no and I that have the right approach to proving it.

From Dirichlet approximation theorem we know we can find integers $p$ and $q$ such that $|\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{q^2}\implies |\frac{q\pi}{2}-p|\lt\frac{1}{q}$ so let $p_n$ be our candidate and $q_n=2k+1$(some increasing odd integer for each $n$, and although this could be an interesting question on its own, I think I'm safe to assume it. As we get close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, the rational approximations have very large numerators and denominators) then $|(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}-p_n|\rightarrow 0$ (monotone decreasing) and since the $2k$ term does nothing in $\cos p_n$, we get $\lim \cos(p_n)=0$. Now it remains to show we don't hit zero inbetween, but we can probably choose $p_n$ so that this doesn't happen.

Does this work? Is there a way to do this without Dirichlet?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah the *infimum* is $-1$.  The *minimum* doesn't exist.

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:algebra-precalculus]?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes. $ n $ can never be equal to $\pi(2k+1)$.

Comment: Fixed in the edit

Comment: You must replace min by 'inf' in your question. Else trivially no.

Comment: Why can you take $q_n=2n+1$?

Comment: @Kaind No, this question is about the minimum. If its "trivially no", please share your answer.

Comment: @user10354138 Poor notation on my part, I will edit it

Comment: @sequencesandseries Check my answer below. I've proved it without Dirichlet's.

Comment: "Does this work?" Absolutely.  "Is there a way to do this without Dirichlet"  in essence probably not. One way or another we have to show some integer "gets arbitrarily" close to the set of $S = \{x|\cos x = 0\} = \{\frac \pi 2+ k\pi|\k \in \mathbb Z\}$... or vice versa... the elements of $S$ get arbitrarily close to an integer.  This follows from one manipulation or another of the Archimedian propery.  It maybe doesn't have to be the *exact* Direchlet theorem but it'd be something fits into its clothing.

Comment: FWIW, here's a live [Sage script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1UEtugzAQ3XOKJ6RIdoKgJUoXSHTJAbgAcp1xZDk1xrgVx-8AUZUu6oX1xu-n8YIWwaJCnWnDWI8-Wf9F18FEpZMdvVhk5ph5zcwYkWA9tClZ903xRj7NQjYZ-IQCE-tSqebB-kQ3ikNUHCHkxlvD_AE12hYvzW_T7o2k2fupFnE5FzjjCLe7-o7fe1L3ztL9KlZhu17y4eMm4QrkDULF9XmB9Ezl0zHYqt4IMXHsIkv_lPJHq8dZBLlpV9h3PP0v37HDaf2bx4Lu_Y1X-4ik3A8lQF_O&lang=sage) that calculates near-zero values of $\cos(n)$ using the continued fraction convergents of $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method works. Here is the complete proof.

**First**, we prove that $$   \inf_{n\in \Bbb Z^*}|\cos(n)| = 0 \tag{1}$$
If we can construct a sequence $\{u_t\}_{t \in \Bbb N^*}\in \Bbb Z^*$ such that
$$u_t \equiv\frac{\pi}{2} +\epsilon_t \pmod{\pi} \tag{2}$$
where $ \epsilon_t \xrightarrow{t\to +\infty}0$, then $|\cos(u_t)| \xrightarrow{t\to +\infty}0$. In other words, $(1)$ holds true (because $|\cos(n)| \ge 0$).

$(2)$ is equivalent to find the sequence $\{(u_t,v_t)\}_{t \in \Bbb N^*} \in (\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ such that
$$\left|u_t -\frac{\pi}{2} -\pi v_t\right|\xrightarrow{t\to +\infty}0\iff \left|\frac{u_t -\frac{\pi}{2}}{v_t} -\pi \right|\xrightarrow{t\to +\infty}0 \tag{3}$$

According to the Dirichlet's approximation theorem
, there exists the sequence $\{(u_t,v_t)\}_{t \in \Bbb N^*}$ such that
$$\left|\frac{u_t}{v_t}-\pi \right| \le \frac{1}{v_t^2} \tag{4}$$
Applying $(4)$ to $(3)$ with a sub-sequence of increasing value of $v_{\sigma(t)}$ (for the sake of simplicity, we abuse the notation and still write $v_t$ instead of $v_{\sigma(t)}$), we have
$$\left|\frac{u_t -\frac{\pi}{2}}{v_t} -\pi \right| \le\left|\frac{u_t }{v_t} -\pi \right| + \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{v_t} \le \left(\frac{1}{v_t^2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{v_t} \right)\xrightarrow{v_t\to +\infty} 0$$

Hence, $(1)$ holds true. We can conclude that $ \inf f = 0$

**Second**, we prove that there doesn't exist $n$ such that $\cos(n) = 0$. It's straightforward because if not, there existed $m \in \Bbb Z$ such that
$$n = \frac{\pi}{2} + m\pi$$
or $$\pi = \frac{n}{\frac{1}{2}+m} \in \Bbb Q$$
which is a contracdiction. We can conclude that $\min f$ doesn't existe

*PS*: about the last question whether there exists another proof without using the Dirichlet's approximation theorem, I haven't yet this proof without using the Dirichlet's approximation theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If a set $S\subset \Bbb R$ has a smallest element $s$, then $\min S=s$. If $S$ has no smallest element, then $\min S$ is undefined.

By contrast, the *infimum* $\inf S$ of a set $S$ is defined as the largest $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $x\le s$ for every $s\in S$. Thus, for instance, the infimum of $(0,1)$ is $0$, although this set has no minimum element.

So now we can say that if $S=\{|\cos n|\;:\;n\in\Bbb Z\}$, then $\inf S=0$; but $\min S$ is undefined, because $|\cos n|$ is non-zero for all integers $n$.

Comment: No, the function in question is not defined outside of the integers, each $n$ in $|cos(n)|$ is an integer. I will edit the question to clarify this further.

Comment: How can you prove that $\inf S=0$? Could it not be that $\inf S=\min S=\epsilon$ for some $0<\epsilon\ll1$?

Comment: @sequencesandseries: you have not understood my answer. I am talking about a _set_ (the same set as yours), not a function. (You don't need to edit your question $-$ it is quite clear on this point.)

Comment: @TonyK He is asking you to prove that min S is undefined. (he wants a rigorous proof of that- he knows the difference between min and inf)

Comment: @Kaind: If he (or she) knows the difference between min and inf, what was the point of your comment "You must replace min by 'inf' in your question"?

Comment: I apologise for jumping the gun on your answer, but I'm still not convinced. How do you know 0 is the infimum of S without assuming the answer?

Comment: I didn't know at that time, that was what he/she meant. Check his follow up comment to my comment

Comment: It's clear that $|\cos n|$ never equals $0$ so $0$ is *a* lower bound.  But it is *not* clear that $0 = \inf S$.  It could be that $\inf S > 0$.  And then it might or might not be that there is an $n$ so that $|\cos n| = \inf S > 0$. ..... It would be *sufficient* to show $\inf S =0$ (and then as $|\cos n|$ will have no lowest value as itself can never be $0$ but can be arbitrarily close).  But we *do* have to show that.  And that is an aspect the OP needs (and provides).

Comment: @fleablood: I have answered the question as stated: Does $\min|\cos n|$ exist? The wording of the question reveals that the OP is confusing min with inf, and I have also tried to address this. But I am not a mind reader.

Comment: We can use continuity of $|\cos x|$. For any episilon there is a delta so that $x$ is within $\delta$ of any $\frac \pi 2 + 2k\pi$ we have $|\cos x|< \epsilon$. So our task could be simply to show that for any $\delta$ there is so $k$ so that $\frac \pi 2 + 2k\pi$ is within $\delta$ of an integer.  (Which the OP, imo, did successfully).

Comment: You may not be a mind reader but you ought to be a post reader.  It is very clear the OP is asking is there a least value of $|\cos n|$ that is reached. Which you did *not* answer.  You seem to assume that $\inf |\cos n| = 0$  but say nothing about why that should be assumed. It's true $|\cos n| > 0$ always but so is $\frac 14 + \frac 1n$.  But $\inf (\frac 14 + \frac 1n) \ne 0$.  So why should $|\cos n|$?  How do we know that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is and $n$ where $|\cos n| < \epsilon$.  You never answered that.

Comment: @fleablood: well, pardon me for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be any fixed natural number. We first note that $n$ can never be an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

WLOG let the nearest odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $n$ be $ < n$. Let this odd multiple be denoted by $\pi_n$ and let this distance be $d_n = n - \pi_n$. Now let the decimal expansion of $\pi$ be $3\cdot a_1 a_2 .. a_i .. $. As this series converges to $\pi$, there exists $r \geq 1$ s.t. $d_n > 3 - (3\cdot a_1 a_2 .. a_r)$. Then we can see that the number $n + 3\cdot a_1 a_2 .. a_r \times 10^r$ is closer to $\pi_n + \pi*10^r$ than $n$ is closer to $\pi_n$. Formally:
$$
\begin{align*}
0 < n + 3\cdot a_1 a_2 .. a_r \times 10^r - (\pi_n + \pi*10^r) 
&= d_n - (0.a_{r+1} a_{r+2} ...)  < d_n
\end{align*}
 $$

Hence for any $n$, I've found a another $n' = n + 3\cdot a_1 a_2 .. a_r \times 10^r$ with a smaller value of $|\cos(n)|$, as it's closer to an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (this can be formalized by the continuity of $|\cos x|$ and noting that $\cos(n) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} + d_n) \land \cos(n') = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+ d_{n'}) $ where $0 < d_{n'} < d_n$). For the $ > n$ case, we subtract $\pi * 10^r$ instead of adding.

Comment: This answer actually even proves $\inf_n | \cos (n) | = 0$.